# Two javascript functions not called when return type function is first called

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to call 2 functions onkeypress out of which first function is return type; and second function is not getting called
but if use in reverse order it is working

**Requirement:**

> OnKeyPress, the key should be validated. if number, accept the value
>   in TextBox then copy the value into another textbox; If not a number,
>   then do nothing

Correct Order but 2nd function is **not** getting called;

```
<input type="text" name="no_of_units" id="no_of_units" size="5" 
onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);calc_exchange();">
```

In Reverse order both functions are working. I need the **isNumberKey** function to be called first.

```
<input type="text" name="no_of_units" id="no_of_units" size="5"
 onkeypress="calc_exchange();return isNumberKey(event);"
```

Functions :

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
      {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;
         return true;
      }
function calc_exchange()
{
var raw1=document.getElementById("no_of_units").value;
document.getElementById("next_no_of_units").value=raw1;
}
```

I need the following order of function to be called;

> 1. return isNumberKey(event)
> 2. calc_exchange()

Comment: return means done!go back so no statement after return will be executed.

Comment: is there any function afterKeyPress ?

Comment: nope! but you can use onkeydown and onkeyup events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can't call anything after return therefore you can try this. if wrong input raise alert.

```
<input type="text" name="no_of_units" id="no_of_units" size="5" 
onblur=calcexchange() onkeypress="isNumberKey(event)">
....
function isNumberKey(evt)
      {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            alert("Wrong I/P");
             evt.focus()
      }
```

Comment: its again calling first "calc_Exchange() " .  I have added functions in the question now and see is it possible to write in a single function ?

Comment: basically what you want .? is Funcn1 output determines the call of calexchange ?

Comment: OnKeyPress, the key should be validated if number accept the value in TextBox then copy the value into another textbox; If not a number, then do not do anything.

Comment: add onblur event in text box instead of key press

Answer (score 3):

You can call two javascript functions on keypress where first function is a return type function.

```html
<input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" size="5" 
Onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event,this) && clickButton(event,'imgbtnSearch')">
```

using && operator, we can call two javascript functions on keypress.

Comment: I believe that should work and that's what I tried first. It didn't work for me, that's why I googled and found this question... =/

Answer (score 2):

Calling `return` will execute what's on the right of it and then exit, so naturally the second function is not getting called.

It's hard to answer without knowing what's inside your functions. But I would suggests you attach event handlers with JavaScript and not inline like you are doing. You will get more control that way.

Look here for how to attach event handlers: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: I have added my functions now. Please look at it and let me know if possible.

Comment: is there any function afterKeyPress ?

Answer (score 0):

The `return` doesn't have to be the first statement. Just call the function in order and return the result later.

```
<input type="text" name="no_of_units" id="no_of_units" size="5" 
onkeypress="var result = isNumberKey(event); calc_exchange(); return result;">
```

Returning the result of `isNumberKey` may prevent the default action, if it returns false the input will be ignored. It seems you want prevent non-numbers *and* execute `calc_exchange`. In this case you should only return false *if* the input is no number:

```
if(!isNumberKey(event)) { // validate input
  return false; // it's not a number, so prevent default action (do nothing)
}
calc_exchange(); // it was a number, copy the value
```

The only problem is, at the time you execute `calc_exchange`, the entered number hasn't been inserted into the textbox's value. You could listen to other events though, like when the user input was done:

```
<input type="text" name="no_of_units" id="no_of_units" size="5" 
onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);"
onchange="calc_exchange();" >
```

Comment: As i said, isNumberKey to be returned first and then Calc_Exchange()
Your answer is like reverse... Again return is called second.. i want it to be first.
I have added functions in the question now and see is it possible to write in a single function ?

Comment: @logan But isNumberKey doesn't have any side effects. The order of execution shouldn't even matter with your functions. What exactly do you want to achieve by returning it?

Comment: No : i need the value of raw1 . only if return is True the Pressed Key value will be present in raw1;